# Deployed Lambda function is not sending message to SQS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, permissions, amazon-sqs

When I run my function locally, it will send a message from my Lambda to my SQS queue. However, when I deploy my function and run it, my SQS queue does not receive anything.

Here is my function:

```
async function sendtoQueue(body) {
  var params = {
    DelaySeconds: 0,
    MessageAttributes:{
      "Title": {
        DataType: "String",
        StringValue: "AWS SQS"
      },
      "Author": {
        DataType: "String",
        StringValue: "Wolf"
      }
    },
    MessageBody: body,
    QueueUrl: "https://sqs.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/myqueueurl",
  };

  sqs.sendMessage (params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully sent to Queue", data.Messageld);
    }
  });
};
```

I think I've added all the permissions to my Lambda. To be honest I'm not so sure as this part is not very intuitive. Do I need to do anything else after adding my permissions?

Attached is a screenshot of permissions I should have. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkoX7.png)

Something to note is that my Lambda url uses: [https://us-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/) while my IAM url uses: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/.

Does it matter if they aren't the same? And if so, how do I change it?

My SQS Access Policy is:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "TrustUsers",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-1:myqueue"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is the AWS Lambda function attached to a VPC? If so, is there a particular reason why it was attached?

Comment: Did you attach the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` to the IAM Role used by your function? This will allow debugging information to be sent to CloudWatch logs. (See [Lambda execution role - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html)) What is showing in CloudWatch Logs for your function? (Go to the **Monitoring** tab, click **View in CloudWatch Logs**.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole is attached to the IAM Role however I am not seeing anything on Cloudwatch. Does this mean the error is in my sendtoQueue() function?

Comment: Does CloudWatch Logs at least show that the Lambda function started and ended? It should also show the Duration of that the function took to run.

Comment: I'm not a node.js person, but I know that a lot of people have their Lambda function exit early even when functions are not finished. Something to do with `await`. See: [AWS Lambda function handler in Node.js - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html)

Comment: Make `sendtoQueue` becomes an async function, `return sqs.sendMessage(params).promise()`. And await it when you use it.